# Is it possible to calculate AIC on LSTM?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, aic, lstm

I'm doing a forecast on returns of stocks using ARMA-GARCH models and LSTM. Because of the nature of the data, RMSE, MSE cannot be used. I instead found MAAPE.

Now what I'm trying to understand if I can use AIC on LSTM to evaluate it against ARMA-GARCH models?